# htaccess rewriting between subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have got following folder structure for my domain (domain.com):

/data/images (it´s subdomain name, so it´s accessable via http:// images.domain.com)
/data/www (it´s subdomain name, so it´s accessable via http:// www.domain.com)
/data/.htaccess

And I´m trying to do:
If some image in images.domain.com doesn´t exist, rewrite URL with has request to www.domain.com/somescript.php, so for example
http://images.domain.com/non-existing-image.jpg
should be rewritten to
http://www.domain.com/somescript.php?id=non-existing-image.jpg.

Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|gif|png|bmp)$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /data/www/somescript.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it´s not working. Browser said: "not found". If I tried to change path to "somescript.php" the results were "bad-request" or "not-found".
Via access log I saw that in most cases the path to "somescript.php" is starting from "/data/www/images/" (so final path is non-existing "/data/www/images/www/somescript.php") so I guess I need to get one level higher in my folder structure, but I don´t know how (I guess I´ve already tried almost all combinations).

Could someone please help me how to properly set the combination of RewriteBase and absolute/relative path for the "somescript.php" file?

I also want to note, that if I change the path to "http://www.domain.com/somescript.php" on the last line in my htaccess file, it works well - but due to "http://" it´s redirected and I would like to made as rewrite.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `/` at the beginning of your rewrite rule. In order for it to actually go to another domain, you *must* specify `http://` before the domain, so your last line would need to be like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/somescript.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you don't specify the `http://` it's seen as a relative path and will go off of the domain currently in use, just appending it as a regular relative path.

---

**Or:** (This only works on some setups)

Apache (or whatever you're using) doesn't go off of your user's home directory. It uses the root directory for the **website**. So by specifying the `/` at the beginning of the domain, you're actually saying `/www/images.domain.com/<rest of absolute path>`. However, if both these directories are owned **by the same user**, you can use a relative path to go up to the parent directory and then into the alternative directory, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../www.domain.com/somescript.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I wouldn't recommend this much though, as relative paths can easily become broken.

Comment: Hallo, thank you for your quick reply. If I add "../" at the beginning, the path is still starting from "/data/www/images/"... it´s strange - no matter how many "/../" I add.. With absolute path with "http://" at the beginning it´s working well, but I need rewriting instead of redirecting.

Comment: You may be forbidden from leaving that directory. That's what happens when you reach the highest parent directory possible.

Comment: I also thought it was. Could it be changed somewhere in settings? Or in this case and with this folder structure is the only working way to use redirecting?

Comment: If you have SSH access, you could try setting up a symbolic link inside your images directory that points to the main directory. Just an idea, don't know if it's work. Otherwise, you'd probably be stuck with redirecting unless you can move `somescript.php` to the images directory.